# Should the spheres tag be deprecated?

Tags: discussion, tagging

A review edit for the [spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spheres) tag just popped up on my queue. After looking at the number of questions tagged (7), it seems like an unnecessary tag because it is extremely specific and vague at the same time - specific because it is about *one* kind of surface, vague because it says nothing about the surface. Should this tag be deprecated?

Comment: What's the cost in keeping the tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are over 10000 [geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometry) questions on the site. Often these are Euclidean geometry questions: planimetry or stereometry. There should be some way to break this pile of questions further. There are tags that attempt to do this:

- [circle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/circle) (over 1000 questions)
- [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangle) (over 1000 questions)

Sure, stereometry does not get nearly as much attention in curricula (I recall Plato complaining about this already), and [spheres](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spheres) seems to be a relatively new tag. I think it deserves a chance to stay.

That said: I did not like the proposed wiki at all, and replaced the proposed text with a stub.

Comment: You make a pretty compelling argument. I'm still not a big fan of it but I'll let others weigh in.

Comment: I dare say the tags [circle] and [triangle] should be renamed [circles] and [triangles] respectively.